# Why is maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1 checking out code that "doesn't" exist?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm building on Jenkins.  My mvn build strings look like this (sanitized):

```
-X
-B
clean 
compile
release:clean
release:prepare 
release:perform
-P
PROJECT,!functiontest
-DaltDeploymentRepository=foo-dev-repository::default::${NEXUS_URL}/foo-dev-repository
```

The trouble is that the build fails because of a failing test in a class.  I've deleted that class and committed it.  When I run the build, that class is checked out and the test runs and fails the build.
When I check the code out (same URL as specified in the build), the offending class is not there.  But when I run the Jenkins build, the class is there (it checks out of svn).
I strongly suspect maven-release-plugin.  Can anyone advise me on how to checkout fresh code?  The other plugins include:

```
maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2
build-helper-maven-plugin 3.2.0 
maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1
maven-ear-plugin 2.7
maven-deploy-plugin 2.5.3 <skip>true</skip>
maven-javadoc-plugin 3.2.0   <doclint>none</doclint>
```

Comment: How do you checkout the code in Jenkins? Or in a pipeline? Apart from the the `clean compile` is not necessary while using `release:prepare release:perform` ... and why do you need profiles like `PROJECT` and `!functiontest` ?

Comment: i don't think I need the clean compile strings either.  I try make a release profile and add it to the release plugin configs.  I'll remove the profile strings